# Populate DataTable with nested dictionary result

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

Been coding in C# for only 2 months: I have a dictionary result of type:
`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>>`

I have been able to console write it to be as follow:

`R&D
  Trainer   3000
  Developer 6000
  Consultant    0
Dev
  Trainer   0
  Developer 4000
  Consultant    5000`

As you can see the inner dictionary have the same 'keys'. I tried to put them into a dataTable by:

```
          var columns = l.GroupBy(d => d.Department, (key, items) => key).ToList();


        dt.Columns.Add("Function");
        foreach (var column in columns)
            dt.Columns.Add(column);
       foreach (var dict in result2)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(dict.Key );

                foreach (var dict2 in dict.Value)
                {

                    DataRow row2 = dt.NewRow();

                    row2["Function"] = dict2.Key;
                    row2[dict.Key] = dict2.Value;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row2);

                Console.WriteLine("  " + dict2.Key + "\t" + dict2.Value);
                }

        }
```

The dataTable result in GridView:

`|---------------------|--------------|-------------|
|      Function       |     R&D      |  Dev        |
|---------------------|--------------|-------------|
|      Trainer        |   3000       |             |
|---------------------|--------------|-------------|
|   Developer         |   6000       |             |
|---------------------|--------------|-------------|
|  Consultant         |     0        |             |
|---------------------|--------------|-------------|
|   Trainer           |              |    0        |
|---------------------|--------------|-------------|
|  Developer          |              | 4000        |
|---------------------|--------------|-------------|
| Consultant          |              |  5000       |
|---------------------|--------------|-------------|`

Preferred result:

`|---------------------|--------------|-------------|
|      Function       |     R&D      |  Dev        |
|---------------------|--------------|-------------|
|      Trainer        |   3000       |      0      |
|---------------------|--------------|-------------|
|   Developer         |   6000       |  4000       |
|---------------------|--------------|-------------|
|  Consultant         |     0        |  5000       |
|---------------------|--------------|-------------|`

I want to either populate the 1st column of the dataTable with distinct keys of the inner dictionary and fill the other columns based on it or create the required dataTable based on the initial dataTable.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've just recently had to do this sort of thing while using 2 different DataTables as I'm not an expert myself I cannot say that this is the fastest way to do this, but this should work for you.

```
string find = "Function = '" + dict2.Key + "'";
DataRow[] foundRows = result.Select(find);
if (foundRows.Length > 0)
{
    DataRow row1 = foundRows[0];
    row1[dict.Key] = dict2.Value;
}
else
{
    DataRow row2 = dt.NewRow();
    row2["Function"] = dict2.Key;
    row2[dict.Key] = dict2.Value;
    dt.Rows.Add(row2);
}
```

EDIT: You should put this code inside your last foreach.

[Results from testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkQQK.png)

Comment: Thanks man! Works like charm. I knew there had to be a reference to my columns in the inner foreach but wasn't sure how. I will test it on large datasets and see how it goes.